# How to distinguish NoneType with regex function?

Tags: regex, if-statement, types, boolean, conditional-statements

Here are two very basic examples of the problem that I am currently encountering in my work:

```
import re
type(re.search('(Bob)(.*)(Builder)', "Bob the Builder" , re.IGNORECASE))
```

returns `_sre.SRE_Match` and

```
import re
type(re.search('(Bob)(.*)(Builder)', "the Builder" , re.IGNORECASE))
```

returns `NoneType`. How can I test for the condition whether the data type is `_sre.SRE_Match` or `NoneType`? When I try implementing the code

```
import re
type(re.search('(Bob)(.*)(Builder)', "the Builder" , re.IGNORECASE)) is None
```

it returns `False` when it should be returning `True`. What am I doing incorrect here? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`type(None)` is not `None`, it's `NoneType`. But you don't need `type` here, just use a bool:

```
if re.search(....): 
  print 'found!'
```

Comment: Thank you! I just figured it out! (:

Comment: @Wilson: sure? ;) You're still using `type` in your self-answer.

Comment: There we go! Thank you so much for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I was able to figure it out after attempting to search for solutions online:

```
import re
if re.search('(Bob)(.*)(Builder)', "the Builder" , re.IGNORECASE):
    print 1
else:
    print 2
```